# How to pick config file from flash rather than NVRAM?

Tags: cisco, cisco-7600

My Router (7600)(SUP 720G) NVRAM is corrupt and now I want to load my startup config from flash.

I have already used these Commands but no help.

```
copy running-config disk1:RAM
```

and also used this command to set my default boot config to flash by this

```
config#boot config disk1:RAM
```

i have also run the earlier command of copy again to save the boot config command in running config.
when i reload the router my all configs are lost because it doesn't take them from flash and i loss remote access.

Comment: You need to be in configure mode, before you can use the command boot example: 1. `copy running-config bootdisk:` and 2. `configure terminal` then `(config)#boot config bootdisk:<config name>` or `(config)#boot config disk0:<config name>` that should do it. You can check the boot configuration by using `show bootvar`. `CONFIG_FILE variable =`

Comment: Router#show bootvar
BOOT variable =
CONFIG_FILE variable = bootdisk:running-config
BOOTLDR variable does not exist
Configuration register is 0x8000 (will be 0x2102 at next reload)

Comment: CONFIG_FILE variable should change after using `(config)#boot config disk1:RAM`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this problem by replacing lithium batteries in SUP720. Now Router is taking startup configuration from NVRAM smoothly and also loading it into the  RAM.
We Replaced both RP and RS batteries using these instructions by Cisco.

For More info check this LInk from Cisco.Thank you
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/field-notices/641/fn64131.html

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: wow now there's a gotcha! batteries! on a sup720!